# trying to learn nested structs concept, I have written a short program for understanding but I am running into errors as mentioned below

Tags: c

```
//Program to understand Nested structs in C    
#include <stdio.h>
    
typedef union test {
    float tet;
    struct {
        int bite;
    } p;
} U_test;
    
//union test U_test;
struct U_test.p = {.bite=150};
    
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", U_test.p.bite);
    U_test.tet = 0.0;
    printf("%d", U_test.p.bite);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error code I keep seeing below. Not sure I am doing something wrong here or am I typing something wrong?Please advise. Thanks in advance.

```
error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘.’ token
    struct U_test.p = {.bite=150};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct U_test.p = {.bite=150};
```

That is not the correct syntax to create a variable of the defined union type. It should be:

```
U_test u_test = { .p.bite = 150 };
```

After making that change all the references in `main` which are currently `U_test` need to be changed to `u_test`.

Here is the full program corrected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union test{
    
    float tet;
    struct{
        int bite;
    }p;
}U_test;

//union test U_test;
U_test u_test = { .p.bite=150 };

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", u_test.p.bite);
    u_test.tet = 0.0;
    printf("%d", u_test.p.bite);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps understanding of the concept.